# なぜリストの一部を取り出す時に構文が違うのかわかりません

Tags: python, python3, numpy

以下のようなコードを記述しました。

`dy[0][0:1]` ではリストの最初の数値が取り出せませんでしたので、`dy_sum` で一回形を整え、`dy_sum[0:1]` でリストの最初の数値が取り出せますが、なぜか `dx` についは `dx[0][0:1]` のように、`[0]` を記述しないと取り出せません。

理由がよくわからず困っています。どなたか解説いただけませんでしょうか？

```
import numpy as np

D, N = 8, 7
x = np.random.randn(1,D)
y = np.repeat(x, N, axis=0)

dy = np.random.randn(N, D)
dx = np.sum(dy, axis=0, keepdims=True)

dy_sum = np.sum(dy, axis=0)

print(dy_sum[0:1])
print(dx[0][0:1])
```

Comment: `keepdims=True` としていますので、`dx` の次元数(`ndim`) が `2` になっています。`keepdims=False` とするか、`keepdims` を指定しなければ `dx[0]` で最初の値を取り出す事ができます。

Comment: ndimが2　→　Falseで次元数を1にしてやるとdx[0]が取り出せました！keepdimsはまだ馴染めませんが注意していきます！ありがとうございました

Comment: @yokomizo-groove さん> もし問題が解決された場合は、解決方法を回答として投稿し、質問を解決済みにしていただけませんか？詳しくは、こちらをご一読ください: [自分の質問に回答できますか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 2):

`keepdims=True` としているので、`dx` の次元数(`ndim`) が `2` になっています。
`keepdims=False` とするか、`keepdims` を指定しなければ `dx[0]` で最初の値を取り出す事ができます。

ndim が `2` → False で次元数を `1` にしてやると `dx[0]` が取り出せました。

---

*この投稿は [@ladle さんのコメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/66270/%e3%81%aa%e3%81%9c%e3%83%aa%e3%82%b9%e3%83%88%e3%81%ae%e4%b8%80%e9%83%a8%e3%82%92%e5%8f%96%e3%82%8a%e5%87%ba%e3%81%99%e6%99%82%e3%81%ab%e6%a7%8b%e6%96%87%e3%81%8c%e9%81%95%e3%81%86%e3%81%ae%e3%81%8b%e3%82%8f%e3%81%8b%e3%82%8a%e3%81%be%e3%81%9b%e3%82%93#comment72704_66270) と [@yokomizo-groove さんのコメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/66270/%e3%81%aa%e3%81%9c%e3%83%aa%e3%82%b9%e3%83%88%e3%81%ae%e4%b8%80%e9%83%a8%e3%82%92%e5%8f%96%e3%82%8a%e5%87%ba%e3%81%99%e6%99%82%e3%81%ab%e6%a7%8b%e6%96%87%e3%81%8c%e9%81%95%e3%81%86%e3%81%ae%e3%81%8b%e3%82%8f%e3%81%8b%e3%82%8a%e3%81%be%e3%81%9b%e3%82%93#comment72729_66270) の内容を元に コミュニティwiki として投稿しました。*